# mysql return names of columns that are not 0 in a certain row

Tags: mysql, select

Hello I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | PS0101 | PS0102 | PS0103 |
1  |    1   |    0   |    2   |
2  |    3   |    0   |    0   |
3  |    0   |    0   |    0   |
4  |    0   |    1   |    0   |
```

Using mysql, I am trying to return the names of the columns that are more than 0 for one specified user.

This example mysql code is horribly wrong but just for an idea:

```
SELECT column HAVING column > 0 WHERE id = 1;
```

This would return PS0101 and PS0103

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do if I understand well what you want.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN PS0101>0 THEN 'PS0101' ELSE '' END AS column1, 
CASE WHEN PS0102>0 THEN 'PS0102' ELSE '' END AS column2,
CASE WHEN PS0103>0 THEN 'PS0103' ELSE '' END AS column3
FROM table_name
WHERE id = 1;
```

here's a working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/198275/4)

Comment: It's returning this error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN PS0102>0 THEN 'PS0102' ELSE '' END AS column2 CASE WHEN PS0103>0 THEN ' at line 3